# How to get help and to help with development of software

Tags: application-development, development

I am wanting to get some help with a project, and would love to help others. Maybe be on a developer team even. I have looked at the different Ubuntu sites. What site is the better of the sites? Also the sites don't clearly say how to become one. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to become a Developers then Ubuntu Developers guide is the best way to help you.

http://developer.ubuntu.com/

look at there , irrespective of the programming language you know you can develop applications in Ubuntu.

If you want to get help and to help others about your development & all you can look at

Ubuntu - MOTU https://wiki.ubuntu.com/MOTU

as well as you can always be in touch with them from IRC channels like

- #ubuntu-motu
- #ubuntu-beginners
- #ubuntu-dev